# How to search for two distinct expressions inside the same string?

Tags: vba

For the moment I have:

```
position = InStr(1, line, "Instrumentation (0x")
```

which returns the position of "Instrumentation (0x" inside the string `line`.

However, I need to find the positions of two different strings, within `line`. For example, in the string:

```
line = "Foo Instrumentation (0x) Bar Something else Baz"
```

I'd need to get the position of both "Instrumentation (0x" and "Something else", so two values: 5 and 30 for the respective positions.

I could just use the `InStr` function twice, but is there a way to do this in a single computational step?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. It seems like you're saying "I know how to find a substring within a string, how do I do that twice"? For which the obvious answer seems to be "Do the same thing again". Perhaps I'm missing something?

Comment: Hello Dave! I am not showing off anything, I am just looking for an idea which could help me in solving this situation which I am facing. I agree that I was not explicit enough, but let me try again : The thing is that I can not add a second variable to hold the position of the second string and I need to do this in the same computational step. I thought that, maybe someone with more experience could give me a hint

Comment: Sorry - I wasn't suggesting you were showing off, I phrased my comment poorly. I think I understand, and I've tried to include the detail from your comment in your question - please feel free to roll it back or edit it further if I've misrepresented what you mean. To get really useful answers, it might be a good idea to include some other examples of your expected output - for example, if neither string appears in `line`, or one does and the other doesn't, or if one or both of them appear multiple times.

Comment: I suspect, however, that you'll almost certainly find that the cleanest and simplest option will be to just call `InStr` more than once - is there a specific reason you want to only call it once? I very much doubt that there will be a noticeable difference in performance, and certainly not one that warrants the likely additional complexity in the code.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this

```
position = InStr(1, line, "Instrumentation (0x")
if position > 0 then secondPosition = InStr(1, line, "other word")
```